# Synapse Delphi HTTPS SSL GET Request

Tags: delphi, ssl, request, get, ararat-synapse

Only a GET request to a HTTP url works. If i try to request a HTTPS url then it doesn't return anything. I pretty much tried everything. Appreciate any help.

Here's my code:

```
 SynHttp.Sock.CreateWithSSL(TSSLOpenSSL);
 SynHttp.Sock.SSLDoConnect;
 SynHttp.HTTPMethod('GET', 'https://www.google.com/');
 Resp.LoadFromStream(SynHttp.Document);
 HtmlResponse := Resp.Text;
```

SynHTTP is a THTTPSend object.

Comment: No delphi mastermind around? :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with synapse components, but try calling SynHttp.HTTPMethod after .CreateWithSSL and then .SSLDoConnect, if this doesn't work, try SynHttp.Sock.Connect in stead of .SSLDoConnect, hope this works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure:

1. your exe application can access `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll` - the easiest way is to copy them into the directory of your exe.
2. you added `ssl_openssl.pas` and `ssl_openssl_lib.pas` to your project.

Then it should work instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTPSend and headers, works with SSL in HTTPMethod.
If you use in URL 'https:' instead only 'http:', then your request is made by SSL/TLS connection:

```
aURL:='https://api.metadefender.com/v4/file/bzIwMDYxNi1TSW42NDBPVlprTWw3YjRBMQ';

with THTTPSend.create() do begin
  Headers.Add('apikey: 6b337c92c792174a54acd715ab1aae64');
  writeln(botostr(HTTPMethod('GET',aURl)));
  writeln('synapse get: '+StreamtoString3(document)) 
  writeln(itoa(ResultCode)+' '+ResultString);
  Clear;
  Free;
end;
```